# best method to mock http request without use of url in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

I have 2 class like below  I don't have url path for class A what is the best method to test process_get? I tried mocking a http request with request in rest_framework.request but they don't let me  set query_params witch i need to set

```
class A(APIView):
     def process_get(self, request, form):
       pass

class B(A):
  def get(self,request)
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response (what a delay lol) I created a package just for that:

https://github.com/Ori-Roza/drf-api-action

drf-api-action elevates DRF testing with the api-action decorator, simplifying REST endpoint testing to a seamless, function-like experience.

```
from drf_api_action.decorators import action_api
from drf_api_action.mixins import APIRestMixin
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class DummyView(APIRestMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DummyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DummySerializer

    @action_api(detail=True, methods=["get"], serializer_class=DummySerializer)
    def dummy(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=self.get_object())
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


def test_dummy():
    api = DummyView()
    result = api.dummy(pk=1)
    assert result['dummy_int'] == 1
```

I hope this will answer your needs

Comment: OP says they need to set query_params; can you show an example of that?

Comment: @AKX so basically:
either if the request is GET or POST the data is injected as kwargs (as shown in the example, pk is from query_params)